# Does GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister remove Token

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I have created `TokenID` by using `Google Cloud Messaging`.

There is an option of enabling and disabling `Notification` in my `app`.

So does it remove `TokenID` and i need to perform the token generation process again, if i use `GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister()`?

Kindly guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `unregister()` method is deprecated:

> This method was deprecated. Instead use `InstanceID.deleteToken()` or
>   `InstanceID.deleteInstanceID()`.

You can delete a token with `deleteToken()`, or you can delete the instance ID itself with all associated tokens by calling `deleteInstanceID()`.

Check out the corresponding developer's guide article [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation).